# Race conditions for RStudio in Windows

Tags: r, rstudio, race-condition

**Edit: Found the answer to my question and the race was happening inside my code. I found the mistake whilst preparing a working example as suggested by Hong Ooi.**

Has anyone experienced and knows how to prevent race conditions in RStudio for Windows 10?

I've been working in R for some years and noticed lately that every now and then, I get non-repeatable results for reasonably simple calculations.

An example would be:

```
a <- 3
a <- a + 1
b <- a + 1
a
b
```

Normally, the result would be:

```
 a
[1] 4
 b
[1] 5
```

Nevertheless, I do get more often than not, especially in heavy scripts with a lot of calculations:

```
 a
[1] 4
 b
[1] 4
```

When I re-run the script, the result is correct, which means that `a <- a + 1` does get calculated, but not on time for `b <- a + 1` to show the correct result the first time I run the script.

I've read about race conditions and parallel computing in R, but both seem to be something you have to purposely tell R to do, not something R would do by itself.

Windows, on the other hand, seems to be happy to make things go parallel without your consent. When running my script, I see Windows is using up to 12 CPUs in Rsession and up to 2 in RStudio.
[image: Resource monitor during RStudio script execution]

I can force the error or avoid it by moving different parts of the code around, e.g.:

```
a <- 3
a <- a + 1
...
Some code here
...
b <- a + 1
a
b
```

Is this issue known by RStudio users or Windows users and is there a way to avoid this?

System:
Windows 10 pro 64-bit
Inter Core i7-6820HQ
RStudio 1.4, though I have had this in previous versions also.
Output of version in RStudio:

```
> version

platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          0.4                         
year           2021                        
month          02                          
day            15                          
svn rev        80002                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
nickname       Lost Library Book
```

Comment: R is single-threaded so race conditions by definition can't occur. Post a reproducible example

Comment: R is, but RStudio isn't. Though I find it unlikely that the architecture of RStudio should open itself up to anything resembling this kind of race condition.